# Can I say "a folder lies in" when talking about computer folders (directories)?

Tags: colloquialisms, tech-writing

I guess *is located in* is nicer, but is it correct English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal preference, but I wouldn't. Florid language is best kept out of technical writing for the sake of clarity. I would recommend using "is located in `/path/to/parent`" to describe the parent folder's path or "is located at `/path/to/folder`" to describe the folder's own path.

Comment: "folder lies in" is considered florid? oh ok